# Adding days to column in pandas using separate column integers

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried datetime.timedelta on the series, as well as pd.DateOffset. Neither works. I do know I could iterate over this dataframe and add them manually, but I was looking for a vectorized approach.

Example:

```
d = {pd.Timestamp('2015-01-02'):{'days_delinquent':11}, pd.Timestamp('2015-01-15'):{'days_delinquent':23}}
>>> dataf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
>>> dataf
            days_delinquent
2015-01-02               11
2015-01-15               23
```

Just trying to add 11 and 23 days to the rows below. The column I'm adding to in real life is not the index, but I can obviously just make it the index when doing this.

I guess this wasn't self explanatory, but the output would the be a new column with Date(Index in this case) + datetime.timedelta(days=dataf['days_delinquent'])

Comment: I'm trying to add 11 days to 2015-01-02 and 23 days to 2015-01-15. The output would be a new column with [2015-01-13,2015-02-07]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your `days_delinquent` column to `timedelta64[D]` (offset in days) and add it to the index, eg:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {pd.Timestamp('2015-01-02'):{'days_delinquent':11}, pd.Timestamp('2015-01-15'):{'days_delinquent':23}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
df['returned_on'] = df.index + df.days_delinquent.astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

**Much nicer** (thanks [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm)) is to use `pd.to_timedelta` so the units are more easily changed if needs be:

```
df['returned_on'] = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df.days_delinquent, 'D')
```

Gives you:

```
            days_delinquent returned_on
2015-01-02               11  2015-01-13
2015-01-15               23  2015-02-07
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {pd.Timestamp('2015-01-02'):{'days_delinquent':11}, 
    pd.Timestamp('2015-01-15'):{'days_delinquent':23}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

def add_days(x):
    return x['index'] + pd.Timedelta(days=x['days_delinquent'])

df.reset_index().apply(add_days,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0   2015-01-13
1   2015-02-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataf['result'] = [d + datetime.timedelta(delta) 
                   for d, delta in zip(dataf.index, dataf.days_delinquent)]

dataf
Out[56]: 
            days_delinquent     result
2015-01-02               11 2015-01-13
2015-01-15               23 2015-02-07
```